# MySQL Relational Division Query Performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have `students` that are associated many-to-many with `groups` via a join table `groups_students`. Each `group` has a `group_type`, which can either be a `permission_group` or not (boolean on `group_types` table).

I also have `users`, which are also associated many-to-many with `groups` via `groups_users`.

[image]

I want to return all `students` for which a particular `user` is associated with **ALL the student's permission groups**.

I've been lead to believe this requires relational division and here's where I am with it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gs.student_id
FROM groups_students AS gs
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = gs.group_id
INNER JOIN groups_users gu ON gu.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN group_types ON group_types.id = groups.group_type_id
WHERE group_types.permission_group = 1
AND gu.user_id = 37
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM groups_students AS gs2
  WHERE gs2.student_id = gs.student_id
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT gu2.group_id
    FROM groups_users AS gu2
    WHERE gu2.group_id = gs2.group_id AND gu2.user_id = gu.user_id
  )
)
```

This works, but on my live database with over 20,000 rows in `groups_students`, it takes over 3 seconds.

Can I make it faster? I read about doing relational division with `COUNT` but I couldn't relate it to my scenario. Am I able to make cheap gains to bring this query well under half a second execution time or am I looking at a major restructure?

Edit - English language description: Students belong to classes (groups), and users have permission to view certain classes. I need to know the students for which a particular user has permission to view all the (permission) classes for.

`EXPLAIN` for the slow query:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type   | possible_keys                                                | key                                              | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                          |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | gu          | ref    | index_groups_users_on_user_id,index_groups_users_on_group_id | index_groups_users_on_user_id                    | 5       | const                       | 1181 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | groups      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                      | PRIMARY                                          | 4       | my_db.gu.group_id           |    1 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | group_types | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                      | NULL                                             | NULL    | NULL                        |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | gs          | ref    | index_groups_students_on_group_id_and_student_id             | index_groups_students_on_group_id_and_student_id | 4       | my_db.groups.id             |    9 | Using where; Using index       |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | gs2         | ref    | index_groups_students_on_student_id_and_group_id             | index_groups_students_on_student_id_and_group_id | 4       | my_db.gs.student_id         |    8 | Using where; Using index       |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | gu2         | ref    | index_groups_users_on_user_id,index_groups_users_on_group_id | index_groups_users_on_group_id                   | 5       | my_db.gs2.group_id          |   99 | Using where                    |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+--------------------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4776d8/7/0)

Comment: denormalize and add permission group as an attribute to the groups

Comment: @SamD - I tried this but it makes no noticable difference to execution speed. The problem is in the nested subqueries and a large `groups_students` join table.

Comment: 17 and 18 appear in your result, but they don't seem to fit with the criteria

Comment: Students with ids 17 and 18 both belong to group 5 in the test data, which is a permission group that the user is also associated with.

Comment: Why does the query filter on permission groups = 1?

Comment: OK. I think i misunderstood the requirement. You want to know the students for whom the viewing of no class is denied a given user. But I think we need to get to the bottom of Gordon's query first!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I put it in there because I'm only interested in whether the user is or is not associated with a student's permission groups ('can or can not view' in application logic).

Comment: I can see now that I don't need the `permission_group` condition on the subquery because I'm joining the already filtered outer query. I have simplified the query in my question based on this -- but it still runs the same speed unfortunately!

Comment: Can you post your new statement and the explained query.

Comment: Just to check, student 39 is associated with a tutor_group (3) and two subject_groups (21 & 22). Must a user have permission for all three groups, or merely the tutor_group and any one of the subject_groups?

Comment: @Strawberry only the tutor_group, as the tutor_group (group type) is the only one with permission_group = 1. Gordon has found me a lightning fast solution now, but thanks for your help!

Comment: I *think* Gordon's solution can be simplified!

Comment: @Strawberry oh my bad! I'd be interested in any simplification you think you can make :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I want to return all students for which a particular user is associated with ALL the student's permission groups."

I don't really follow your query; it seems so complicated for this purpose.  Instead, I think of it as follows:

1. Generate all students and their permissions
2. Generate all permissions for user 37
3. (outer) Join these together on permissions
4. Be sure that all permissions for a particular student are in the `u37` group

The resulting query is:

```
select student_id
from (SELECT gs.student_id, g.id as group_id
      FROM groups_students gs INNER JOIN
           groups g
           ON g.id = gs.group_id INNER JOIN
           groups_users gu
           ON gu.group_id = g.id INNER JOIN
           group_types gt
           ON gt.id = g.group_type_id
      where gt.permission_group = 1
     ) s left outer join
     (select g.id as group_id
      from groups_users gu INNER JOIN
           groups g
           on gu.group_id = g.id INNER JOIN
           group_types gt
           ON gt.id = g.group_type_id
      where gu.user_id = 37 and gt.permission_group = 1
     ) u37
     on s.group_id = u37.group_id
group by s.student_id
having count(*) = count(u37.group_id);
```

Note:  You can do this without the subqueries.  Despite their overhead, I think they make the query much more understandable.

Comment: Hi Gordon -- I'm not filtering on any specific group, `37` is an arbitrary id of a user as this should produce the Students that the User has permission to view. I'm taking a look at your query now to see if I can tweak it though!

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. The query seems good and has shaved a couple tenths off the overall time, but it still runs in 3.25s ..

Comment: @MikeCampbell . . . Try it again.  I think I'm starting to understand the data and question.  The join was on `group_type_id`, which would have caused a big cartesian product.  I switched it to `group_id`, much more sensible and correct.

Comment: Your latest change and mine combined reduces it to ~17ms. Just need to triple check everything works.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of Gordon's idea...

```
SELECT gs.student_id
  FROM groups_students gs 
  JOIN groups g 
    ON g.id = gs.group_id 
  JOIN group_types gt 
    ON gt.id = g.group_type_id
  LEFT
  JOIN groups_users gu
    ON gu.group_id = gs.group_id
   AND gu.user_id = 37
 WHERE gt.permission_group
 GROUP
    BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(student_id) = COUNT(user_id)
```

Comment: hmmm, i think i can do an INNER JOIN on `groups_users` actually :s. i will revisit this tomorrow, but if i can then yours is great -- thanks!

Comment: I suspect that your sample data set is not properly representative of the problem at hand, which is why it appears that you can do this with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: You were right, my data wasn't good enough to realise that the INNER JOIN wouldn't work. If a student is in more than one permission group, the INNER JOIN doesn't enforce that the user had permission to view them all. With this in mind, Gordon's solution without the (seemingly?) unnecessary join to `groups_users` in the first subselect, is more than twice as fast currently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use subqueries. They are generally slow and should be avoided if possible. Maybe I do not understand your requirements correctly, but I would come up with something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gs.student_id
FROM groups_students AS gs
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = gs.group_id
INNER JOIN groups_users gu ON gu.group_id = groups.id
INNER JOIN group_types ON group_types.id = groups.group_type_id
LEFT JOIN groups_students AS gs2 ON gs2.student_id = gs.student_id
LEFT JOIN groups_users AS gu2 ON gu2.group_id = gs2.group_id AND gu2.user_id = gu.user_id
WHERE group_types.permission_group = 1
AND gu.user_id = 37
AND gs2.student_id IS NULL
AND gu2.group_id IS NULL
```

You can force something to not exist by using a left join and checking, that the right table-column (use the primary key) contains null.